# How can I combine the output of a `For` loop into a list?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am currently writing on a code to get RandomNumbers which are geometrical distributed.

But i need the output in one list because i want to plot the output Can anyone help me? 
Here is the current Code:

```
m := 20
k = RandomReal[{0, 1}, m];
n := 9
p := 0.40
Liste1 = CDF[GeometricDistribution[p], Range[0, n]];
For[
 j = 1,
 j < m + 1,
 j++,
 {
   For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++, If[k[[j]] < Liste1[[i]], Break[]]]; i - 1
   }
  Print[{i - 1, PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], i - 1]}]
 ]
```

Comment: Use `Table` instead of `For`. (`For` is also very slow in _Mathematica_ because, in constrast to C, there is no compiler that optimizes it away.) Moreover, _Mathematica_ is not Maple or Pascal: The assignment operator is `Equal` (`=`), not `SetDelayed` (`:=`). The latter is used in combination with patterns for defining functions.

Comment: *to get RandomNumbers which are geometrical distributed* I might start with `RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[p]]` and take it from there.

Comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 2):

To generate e.g. 1000 random numbers that are geometrically distributed with the probability parameter p=0.4

```
data= RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.4], 1000]
```

To plot the data, use e.g. [ListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) or [Histogram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html?q=Histogram)

As with other high-level functional languages and environments, Mathematica has an extensive library of functions. Initially it might be a bit overwhelming. But in your case, searching for ["random number generation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wolfram%20random%20number%20generation&oq=wolfram%20random%20number%20generation) will get you almost directly to the function RandomVariate

Comment: I need to convert randomnumbers between 0 and 1 by my self with out any given function. Thats what my professor told me...

Comment: Perhaps this would help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485448/prove-the-way-to-generate-geometrically-distributed-random-numbers

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what the restrictions are. You reject [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) since you must do it by yourself "without any given function" -- but you use [`CDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html) and [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html). How about [`InverseCDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseCDF.html)?

```
Clear["Global`*"]

p = 2/5;

n = 1000;

SeedRandom[0]

sample = InverseCDF[GeometricDistribution[p], RandomReal[1, n]];

Show[
 ListPlot[{#[[1]], #[[2]]/n} & /@ Tally[sample], 
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[6]],
 DiscretePlot[PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], x], {x, 0, 14}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image]